# Como llamo funciones dentro de otra funcion

Tags: python

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo donde las tres ultimas funciones retornan un Booleano si una matriz cumple con las condiciones de cada funcion.
Finalmente quiero llamar en is_numerical_matrix a las demas funciones y si la matriz paso la prueba en cada una es decir que retorno True entonces retornar True en la funcion, pero la funcion me da error, no consigo la manera de llamar a las funciones dentro de esta funcion

Este es el codigo(en los comentarios se explica que hace cada funcion)

```
def is_numerical_matrix(matrix):
    if list_of_list == True and len_list == True and is_numeric == True:
        return True
    else:
        return False
   
def is_list_of_list_matrix(matrix):
    """
    Funcion que valida si matrix es una lista de listas.
    """
    index = 0
    while index < len(matrix):
        list_of_list = isinstance(matrix[index], list)
        index += 1
    return list_of_list

def len_list(matrix):
    """
    Funcion que valida si las sublistas de una matriz son del mismo tamaño.
    """
    index = 0
    while index < len(matrix) - 1:
        len_list = len(matrix[index]) == len(matrix[index + 1])
        index += 1
    return len_list

def is_numeric_list(matrix):
    """
    Funcion que valida si las listas en una matriz estan compuestas por numeros.
    """
    for elements in (matrix):
        for element in (elements):
            is_numeric = isinstance(element, int)
    return is_numeric

print(is_numerical_matrix([[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola en la 2da línea del código donde se encuentra el `if list_of_list == ....` las funciones que llamas a lo largo deberías pasarle como argumento el parámetro que requieren esas funciones. De esta forma te quedaría algo así:

```
def is_numerical_matrix(matrix):
    if is_list_of_list_matrix(matrix) and len_list(matrix) and is_numeric(matrix):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Otro detalle, la primer función que escribiste en el `if` es `is_list_of_list_matrix`, no `list_of_list`

Luego si cada función retorna un booleano entonces no deberia hacer falta poner "`== True`"

Comment: También se podría reducir simplemente con `return  is_list_of_list_matrix(matrix) and len_list(matrix) and is_numeric(matrix) ` si va a devolver boleamos no es necesario meterlos en un`if/else`

Comment: exacto, también es una opción

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono al fin el codigo, tomare sus consejos de reducir el codigo... Muchas graciass